# How to retrieve public URL of a file via cmd line?

Tags: ubuntu-one

How can I get the public URL of a file via a command? I need to do this within a Lua script, so Python or whatever else API's are offered aren't any good.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I see the ubuntu-one tag now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a public URL for a file via the commandline, you do

```
u1sdtool --publish-file=filename
```

if the file is already published, it will return the existing URL; otherwise, it will publish the file and return the newly created URL.

Comment: Thank you... can you help perfect it? I can't quite figure it out, trying it on an already published file (while U1 is disconnected though... still uploading my music collection): http://paste.pocoo.org/show/44KX0W3KliP9tZikBtku/

Comment: add a backslash before the space in "Ubuntu One", or put quotes around the whole path.